# Rails: path in File.read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

In user_mailer.rb

```
def welcome_email(message)
@message = message   
@image=@message.pics_file_name  #Getting file name
attachments['@image']=File.read('path/@image') #Have to get path here
mail(:to => @message.mailto, :subject => 'Welcome to my site')
end
```

I'm retrieving the file name from database.I have to use the file name in File.read() for sending file as attachment to a specified mail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
def welcome_email(message)
@message = message   
@image=@message.pics_file_name  #Getting file name

#you need to give application root path here 
attachments[@image]=File.read("#{Rails.root}/your assets path/#{@image}") #Have to get path here
mail(:to => @message.mailto, :subject => 'Welcome to my site')
end
```

your assets path may be , if you are storing the assets in public directory then path will be

```
attachments[@image]=File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/assets/#{@image}")
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dir structure looks like this:

```
 App base Directory
   |
   |-> mail_resources
        |
        | -> images
              |
              |-> image_file
```

Then you can use

```
Rails.root.join("mail_resources", "images", "image_file")
```